# Speed up text comparisons (with sparse matrices)

Tags: text, comparison, matrix, analysis

I have a function which takes two strings and gives out the cosine similarity value which shows the relationship between both texts.

If I want to compare 75 texts with each other, I need to make 5,625 single comparisons to have all texts compared with each other.

Is there a way to reduce this number of comparisons? For example sparse matrices or k-means?

I don't want to talk about my function or about ways to compare texts. Just about reducing the number of comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Ben says it's true, to get better help you need to tell us what's the goal.

For example, one possible optimization **if you want to find similar strings** is storing the string vectors in a spatial data structure such as a quadtree, where you can outright discard the vectors that are too far away from each other, avoiding many comparisons.

Comment: Yes, I want to find similar strings. More details are in my comment on Ben's answer. My database (MySQL) seems to have these spatial types: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-spatial-datatypes.html Theres's nothing about a quadtree!?

Comment: Many kinds of spatial indexes can serve you well. Read about those available form MySQL.

Comment: I've read a lot now about these spatial features. I've added a paragraph about it to my question. Can you give me further help?

Comment: I suggest you to open a different question about how to use mysql spatial extensions for your use case and to leave this question as it was in case somebody has a better algorithm to compare your strings.

Comment: Good idea :) The question about MySQL's spatial features is now here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460618/speed-up-text-comparisons-feature-vectors-with-spatial-mysql-features So in this question here, I'm looking for algorithms which can help.

Answer (score 1):

If your algorithm is pair-wise, then you probably can't reduce the number of comparisons, by definition.

You'll need to use a different algorithm, or at the very least pre-process your input if you want to reduce the number of comparisons.

Without the details of your function, it's difficult to give any concrete help.

Comment: My function calculates the cosine similarity. It takes two arrays containing the tokens/words of the texts. I think you can only calculate cosine similarity pair-wise so you can't reduce the number of comparisons for cosine similarity, right?

Comment: Yes, but if you're interested only in certain data, you might be able to avoid doing some comparisons, like Vinko mentioned for similar strings.