# Speed up text comparisons (feature vectors) with spatial MySQL features

Tags: mysql, comparison, spatial, similarity

I have a function which takes two arrays containing the tokens/words of two texts and gives out the cosine similarity value which shows the relationship between both texts.

The function takes an array $tokensA (0=>house, 1=>bike, 2=>man) and an array $tokensB (0=>bike, 1=>house, 2=>car) and calculates the similarity which is given back as a floating point value.

```
function cosineSimilarity($tokensA, $tokensB) {
    $a = $b = $c = 0;
    $uniqueTokensA = $uniqueTokensB = array();
    $uniqueMergedTokens = array_unique(array_merge($tokensA, $tokensB));
    foreach ($tokensA as $token) $uniqueTokensA[$token] = 0;
    foreach ($tokensB as $token) $uniqueTokensB[$token] = 0;
    foreach ($uniqueMergedTokens as $token) {
        $x = isset($uniqueTokensA[$token]) ? 1 : 0;
        $y = isset($uniqueTokensB[$token]) ? 1 : 0;
        $a += $x * $y;
        $b += $x;
        $c += $y;
    }
    return $b * $c != 0 ? $a / sqrt($b * $c) : 0;
}
```

If I want to compare 75 texts with each other, I need to make 5,625 single comparisons to have all texts compared with each other.

Is it possible to use MySQL's spatial columns to reduce the number of comparisons?

I don't want to talk about my function or about ways to compare texts. Just about reducing the number of comparisons.

**MySQL's spatial columns**

- You create spatial columns with: CREATE TABLE abc (clmnName TYPE)
- possible types are listed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/gis-geometry-class-hierarchy.html)
- [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-spatial-values.html) is how I select the data later [e.g. MultiPointFromText() or AsText()]
- You insert values like this: INSERT INTO clmnName VALUES (GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)'))

But how do you use this for my problem?

PS: I'm looking for ways to reduce the number of comparisons with algorithms [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456343/speed-up-text-comparisons-with-sparse-matrices). Vinko Vrsalovic told me that I should open another question for the spatial features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `R-Trees` in general can index data with arbitrary number of dimensions, `MySQL` spatial abilities are only limited to `Geometry` types (`2` dimensions).

If your vectors are `2`-dimensional **and** you can normalize them, then do the following:

- Split the circle into twice the number of angles which fit your differences
- Find the `MBR` of vectors with given cosine difference from the center of each sector
- Find all vectors within the `MBR`
- Do the fine filtering for exact difference.

In this case, however, it will be better just to precaculate the angle of the value and index it with a plain `B-Tree` index.

Comment: I've added some details about my function and the vectors which the function takes. Do you think your approach is possible with these?

Comment: Since your vectors are located on the surface of the orthotope, it would be possible if you had a fixed number of dimensions (that is a fixed set of tokens) and `MySQL` would be able to build an `R-Tree` on this number of dimensions. Since neither of these is possible, this solution is not viable too.

Comment: So I can forget about this approach with MySQL's spatial features and look for another way? No possibility?

Comment: `@marco92w`: of course never say "never" but as for now I don't see a way to use `MySQL`'s spatial abilities here.

Comment: You can certainly implement an R-Tree in code, either extending MySQL or in PHP (or a PECL extension). It's not a minor endeavour, for sure.

Comment: In fact KD Trees might be a better choice for this kind of scenario

Comment: `@Vinko Vrsalovic`: I'm not sure that `R-Trees` or `KD-trees` will suit this task at all, given that the number of dimensions is not known in advance.

Comment: R-Trees and KD-Trees are not in the list of spatial types I posted. Where do I find these types? And Quassnoi is right: Maybe there are 1,000,000 possible features since the amount of words is increasing every day.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you have only **75 * 74 / 2 = 2775** comparisons. You compare every word with 74 others, but you don't need to compare word1 with word2 and again word2 with word1. So it gives **half of comparisons less**.

Comment: Thanks, that's right. :) But it's still a lot. And I don't compare words but texts.